# Предварительные объявления классов

Tags: c++, qt, header

Зачем нужно предварительные объявления классов в заголовочном файле?

```
#ifndef UIBLUE
#define UIBLUE

#include QDialog

class QCheckBox; 
class QLable;    
class QLineEdit; 


class UiBlue : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

};

#endif // UIBLUE
```

Comment: В том коде, который вы привели, они низачем не нужны. Также: что такое `#include QDialog`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если ваш заголовочный файл `uiblue.h` (я предполагаю, что он так называется), использует класс `QCheckBox` (и т.п.) только для того, чтобы объявлять указатели/ссылки на этот класс и не пытается доступаться к членам этого класса, то вы можете попробовать сэкономить на времени компиляции. А именно, вы можете не включать заголовочный файл `<QCheckBox>` в ваш заголовочный файл, а просто выполнить предварительные объявления класса `QCheckBox` и других требуемых классов, как это сделано в вашем примере.

Включить `<QCheckBox>` куда-то потом вам все таки придется, но при соответствующей организации определения методов вашего класса `UiBlue`, включить `<QCheckBox>` вам придется только в файл(ы) реализации класса `UiBlue`, которые работают с внутренностями класса `QCheckBox`. Скажем, это будет файл `uiblue.cpp`.

Таким образом другие файлы вашего проекта, которые включают в себя `uiblue.h`, не будут тем самым вызвать еще и косвенного включения заголовочных файлов `<QCheckBox>`, `<QLineEdit>` и пр., что потенциально может ускорить компиляцию этих других файлов.